# Why is my react-select dropdown not populated in NextJS client-side rendering pages?

Tags: next.js, react-select

```
  "use client";

  import { React } from "react";
  import Select from "react-select";

  const page = () => {
  return (
     <>
        <Select options={[
           { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
           { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
        /> 
     </>
  );
  }
  export default page;
```

Working on a NextJS 13 project, all pages are client render pages. Below react-select is not working.
NextJS react-select dropdown not populated and its empty. Please help.

Comment: Did you have any errors in the console after running the code @user4032429?

Comment: Please refer to how to use this https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/master#installation-and-usage

Comment: What's your version of NextJs?